# How to prove that Lp norm exists?

Tags: normed-spaces, lp-spaces

how do I show that

> $$\sqrt[\leftroot{-1}\uproot{4}p]{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^p} {2^n}}$$

is finite?

I believe this is a type of Lp norm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply ratio test. $\frac {a_{n+1}} {a_n} \to \frac  1 2$.

Comment: oh yea, I should show convergence. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The sum converges by the ratio test, or the root test.